# category of rings has all limits? building P^1 from gluing two copies of A^1

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

What is the limit (i.e. inverse limit) of the following diagram of (unital, commutative) rings:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
&& k[s] \\
&& @VVV \\
k[t] @>>> k[s,t]/(st-1)
\end{CD}
$$
where the two maps are the natural ones $t \to \overline{t}$ and $s \to \overline{s}$?

I read that category of rings has all limits. But on the level of affine varieties, what I am trying to do is gluing two affines to form $P^1$, so in Rings the limit should not exist ... so I am confused where I am going wrong.

If we forget the $k[s,t]/(st-1)$, then the limit is $k[t] \times k[s]$, but that's all I know,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring $k[s,t]/(st-1)$ can be described clearly as $k[s,s^{-1}]$, the ring of Laurent polynomials, and the two maps you are considering are then the inclusions $k[s]\to k[s,s^{-1}]$ and $k[s^{-1}]\to k[s,s^{-1}]$. The limit of your diagram is clearly $k$.

This is quite the expected result: the only regular functions on the projective line are the constant ones.

Notice that the colimit of the diagram $\mathbb A^1\leftarrow \mathbb A^1\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb A^1$ that is the version of yours in the category of affine schemes may well have a colimit (and it does: it's the single point $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$), but that has nothing to do with the colimit of the same diagram viewed in the category of quasi-projective varieties, say, simply because those are different categories!

Comment: In the last paragraph, the arrows in your diagram should go the other way, and you should be talking about colimits.

Comment: Ok, if you prefer!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (but I could very well have gotten things mixed up), the adjunction between $\operatorname{Spec}$ and the global sections functor should show that $\Gamma$ takes colimits to limits, and $\operatorname{Spec}$ takes colimits to limits.  However, this gives a counterexample to show that $\operatorname{Spec}$ does not take limits to colimits.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Said another way, Spec is an *equivalence* between commutative rings (op) and affine schemes. So it certainly sends limits to colimits!

Comment: OK, I was thinking of $\operatorname{Spec}$ as a contravariant functor from commutative rings to schemes (and giving an argument for why the limit of the given diagram of rings should be canonically isomorphic to $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1_k, \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_k})$), and similarly the functor of global sections as a contravariant functor from schemes to commutative rings.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Your observation seems right and is nice (namely that this example shows the functor Spec:Rings to Schemes (not Affine Schemes) does not send limits to colimits, whereas general categorical properties of adjunctions show that Spec sends colimits to limits. In other words, replacing Rings with Rings^op, then Spec:Rings^op\ to Schemes is an example of a right adjoint functor that does not preserve colimits)